# Создание zip файла без заданных файлов

Tags: python, zip

Пишу на Python.
Требуется создать `zip` архив без некоторых каталогов и чтоб в архиве были только файлы данной директории.
Пробовал использовать `make_archive` из `shutil`, но не нашел исключение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте сами список исключений

```py
import zipfile
import os

# Находим все в текущей директории
currentDirectory = os.listdir(".")

# Создаем список файлов
list_files = []
for currentFile in currentDirectory:  
    list_files.append(currentFile)

# Удаляем ненужное
del_list = ["folder1", "folder2"]
for i in del_list:
    if i in currentDirectory:
        list_files.remove(i)

# Пишем в архив
with zipfile.ZipFile('arh.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    for i in list_files:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(i):
            for file in files:
                path = os.path.join(root, file)
                myzip.write(path)
```

Comment: Рекурсии не хватает или он сам папки упаковывает?

Comment: Да, нужна рекурсия

Comment: Да будет нужна. Поправил ответ.